# fast and memory-efficient way of converting byte[] to arrays of primitives

Tags: c#, arrays

I am passed a byte array which is then converted to arrays of primitives using System.Buffer.BlockCopy. Essentially my code looks like this:

```
    void Convert(byte[] b)
    {
        int[] i1 = new int[100];    // real arrays much larger
        double[] d1 = new double[100];
        int iPos=0, iSize;

        iSize = i1.Length * sizeof(int);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, iPos, i1, 0, iSize);
        iPos += iSize;

        iSize = d1.Length * sizeof(double);
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(b, iPos, d1, 0, iSize);
        iPos += iSize;

        //etc: lots of arrays

        b=null;         
    }
```

This is quite performant, but it's memory usage is obviously 2x the size of my byte array until b is freed.

Is there any way to directly cast sections of the byte array to my primitive arrays? One that does not involve copying the data (therefore doesn't double the memory usage), and presumably is even faster?

Comment: Do you know in advance what sections of the array are which type of value?

Comment: You could write one half of the code in unsafe code, so you don't need say the `double[]` and instead word on `double*`. | There is also a really ugly hack that re-interpret casts the arrays, but that's a really bad idea, so you shouldn't use that.

Comment: can you show me how to do your first idea? I haven't used unsafe code before

Comment: Disregard my answer... I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I wonder where the array if bytes is coming from? If it is read from a file then using `Streams` and multi-threading you can make it much faster with smaller memory footprint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **unsafe** code (I don't if you are allowed to use it). But you can try something like this (no need to use extra arrays, just the array of bytes):

```
    unsafe public void Convert(void* b)
    {
        int i;

        double* asDouble = (double*)b;
        double sum1 = 0.0;
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++, asDouble++)
            sum1 += *asDouble;

        int* asInt = (int*)asDouble;
        int sum2 = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++, asInt++)
            sum2 += *asInt;
    }

    public unsafe void SomeThing()
    {
        byte[] rawbytes = new byte[44000];

        // Fill the "rawbytes" array somehow

        fixed (byte* ptr = rawbytes)
        {
            Convert(ptr);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using unsafe code. One solution using a union (what my not be applicable in your situation)

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static unsafe void Main()
        {           
            var x = new ByteDoubleUnion();

            x.bytes[0] =  24;
            x.bytes[1] =  45;
            x.bytes[2] =  68;
            x.bytes[3] =  84;
            x.bytes[4] = 251;
            x.bytes[5] =  33;
            x.bytes[6] =   9;
            x.bytes[7] =  64;

            // Prints pi.
            Console.WriteLine(x.doubleValue);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal unsafe struct ByteDoubleUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal Double doubleValue;

        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal fixed Byte bytes[8];
    }
}
```

and one solution just casting pointers.

```
namespace TestApplication
{
    using System;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static unsafe void Main()
        {           
            var bytes = new Byte[] { 24, 45, 68, 84, 251, 33, 9, 64 };

            fixed (Byte* p = &bytes[0])
            {
                // Prints pi, too.
                Console.WriteLine(*((Double*)p));
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: woah! That literally is 100x faster than doing the GCHandle.Alloc method!! This needs to be shared!

Answer (score 0):

This is an attempt with unioned structure of arrays (unlike the array of struct in other postings) because this should be faster.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct ByteBuffer
{        
    public const int IntSize=10;
    public const int DoubleSize=5;
    public const int IntBytes=sizeof(int)*IntSize;
    public const int DoubleBytes=sizeof(double)*DoubleSize;

    // Int array is unioned with byte array
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    fixed int int_array[IntSize];
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    fixed byte int_array_bytes[IntBytes];

    // Double array us unioned with byte array
    [FieldOffset(IntBytes)]
    fixed double double_array[DoubleSize];
    [FieldOffset(IntBytes)]
    fixed byte double_array_bytes[DoubleBytes];

    // Take array of bytes and distribute it 
    // by byte to each array
    public ByteBuffer(byte[] b)
    {
        fixed(byte* ptr=int_array_bytes)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<IntBytes; i++)
            {
                ptr[i]=b[i];
            }
        }
        fixed(byte* ptr=double_array_bytes)
        {

            for(int i=0; i<DoubleBytes; i++)
            {
                ptr[i]=b[IntBytes+i];
            }
        }
    }
    // Convert unmanaged array to managed array
    public int[] ToIntArray()
    {
        int[] result=new int[IntSize];
        fixed(int* ptr=int_array)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<IntSize; i++)
            {
                result[i]=ptr[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    // Convert unmanaged array to managed array
    public double[] ToDoubleArray()
    {
        double[] result=new double[DoubleSize];
        fixed(double* ptr=double_array)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<DoubleSize; i++)
            {
                result[i]=ptr[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Load up with test data
        byte[] data=new byte[..];
        // I tested with 10 ints and 5 doubles encoded into bytes

        //Now to test the Fast conversion
        ByteBuffer bb=new ByteBuffer(data);
        int[] data1=bb.ToIntArray();
        double[] data2=bb.ToDoubleArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it appears to be slower that the OP. Oh, well.